# Background size shrinks from 'cover' to 50% when using a keyframe animation on 'transform: scale' in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate the 'transform: scale' property of a ::before pseudo element from scale(1) to scale(1.1), which is meant to be the animated background of a div which covers the whole viewport. The background-size is set to 'cover' and displays correctly on page load, but when the animation kicks in after a short delay, the background shrinks to about 50% of the viewport. Everything works as expected in Safari, Chrome and Opera (on Mac), but on Firefox (Mac) the behaviour is as described above. On top of that, when resizing the browser window down to a smaller size, everything displays fine again, so to see the issue in Firefox, the browser window needs to be at least wider than about 1000px.

Example below (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YuY4U/embedded/result/).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Animation Test Case</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>This is a div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div::after {
  background: url("http://fineartamerica.com/images-simple-print/images-medium/33-landscape-odon-czintos.jpg") top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  -moz-animation: bg-anim 10s linear 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bg-anim 10s linear 2s infinite;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
@-moz-keyframes bg-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bg-anim {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
@keyframes bg-anim {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the background-size property to a percentage value, but it didn't fix the problem and is not really a solution for my project. I've also tried changing the scale values to 1 and 0.9, which works fine, but then the background doesn't cover the whole viewport which is not acceptable for my situation either.

Any ideas on how to work around this issue? Have I missed something obvious or could this be a browser bug or browser-specific implementation discrepancy even?

Comment: no `<! DOCTYPE html>` and `div::after` in firefox use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `div:after`

Comment: If you append /show to the url in jsfiddle, it will display full window

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've fixed the doctype and added a jsfiddle link. The ::after/:after change makes no difference in latest Firefox (Mac) as far as I know.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in latest (29.0.1) Firefox for Windows. But just for correctness you should position your div relative so that the absolute position of the pseudo element refers to the div and not the body element. But this has nothing to do with your "problem".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Interesting to know, that the issue doesn't seem to be present on Windows. I can still reproduce it on latest Firefox for Mac (29.0.1). The position of the div is missing, because I tried to strip down everything from the example that is not really necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on Firefox on Mac when opening http://jsfiddle.net/YuY4U/embedded/result/. I believe the problem has something to do with jsfiddle.net - the result is in an iframe and that seems to cause the issue on Firefox. Here is the result [out of the iframe](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YuY4U/show/light/) which is the same result as in Chrome, and again [the same code on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ziluqupo/1) which seem to work fine in Firefox too

Comment: I am still seeing the issue on both of the links you provided. I originally discovered the problem outside of jsfiddle with no iframe involved, so it would have really surprised me if this was the root of the issue.

Comment: it is not a jsfiddle problem for sure; firefox related